# How to evaluate the limit where x>>a?

Tags: limits, physics

In physics, I was trying to evaluate an integral but in the end I had to evaluate a limit where x is far greater than a.

There was a solution, however, I can't seem to understand how they evaluate it.

[image: Given solution]

Why are these expressions equal to each other?

Comment: "Equal" is a strong word. That being said, it's a common abuse of terminology in physics. What they really mean is "it's so close that the difference is negligible", for some notion of "negligible" (for instance, if $x\ll a$, then $\sqrt{x^2 + a^2}\approx x$, but that difference wasn't negligible enough in this application).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have only used binomial approximation, it is frequently used in physics.

If $\epsilon<<1$ then $(1+\epsilon)^r\approx 1+r\epsilon$. Here $\epsilon=\frac{a^2}{x^2}$

Answer (score 0):

The function was approximated with it's first order taylor polinomial:
$$(1+\varepsilon)^r\approx 1+r \varepsilon$$
When $\varepsilon$ is small enough.
To be more precise, we could write
$$(1+\varepsilon)^r=1+r\varepsilon+o(\varepsilon)$$
But the physicist tend to avoid the error term.

In your case, $\varepsilon=a^2/x^2$.

This approximation can also be derived from the definition of differentiability at $x=0$, i.e. it's the best linear approximation around $x=0$:
$$f(\varepsilon)=f(0)+f'(0)\varepsilon+o(\varepsilon)$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You have to show that $$\frac{1}{x}\left(1+\frac{a^2}{x^2}\right)^{-1/2}\approx \frac{1}{x}\left(1-\frac{a^2}{2x^2}\right)$$ for $$x>>a$$

Comment: Yes, I'm quite aware, that was what I needed help showing.